# generate array of random 16 byte in hex

Tags: c++

I want to generate array of 16 byte in hex like this in C or C++11:

```
const uint8_t alice[16] = { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf };
```

How can I do that? A sample code would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`std::independent_bits_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/independent_bits_engine) to perform the extraction:

```
// Array of random chars
std::vector<unsigned char> chars(16);

// Random bits generator
std::independent_bits_engine<std::default_random_engine, CHAR_BIT, unsigned char> engine;

// Generate the array
std::generate(begin(chars), end(chars), std::ref(engine));
```

Comment: @RoshanMehta: It will store the result in the `chars` vector.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<16;i++){printf("%c", chars[i]);} This prints binary data.

Comment: @RoshanMehta: (int) chars[i];